# Passing created object instance to mapper

Tags: c#, sharepoint, mapping, automapper, repository-pattern

I have one problem with some SharePoint Library. I would like to map my 'Model' object to 'ListItem' object. Unfortunately the 'ListItem' object doesn't have any constructor and I need to initialize it with function which are inside SharePoint Library. Is it possible to give (before mapping) an instance of mapped object?

```
    public void AddToList(Model model)
    {
        // 'new ListItem()' is fobbiden. 'CreateListItemInstance()'  
        // creates 'instance' using client context, list name which aren't
        // inside 'model' object. 
        ListItem instance = this.CreateListItemInstance(); 

        // (Model -> ListItem) It throws exception, because automapper
        // try to create instance of ListItem.
        ListItem parsedItem = Mapper.Map<ListItem>(model); 

        // I would like to have something like below:
        // Mapper.Map<ListItem>(model).UseInstance(instance);


        this.SharePointListItemRepository.Insert(parsedItem);
        this.SharePointListItemRepository.Save();
    }
```

Update (12/22/2017)

I used ResolutionContext to pass instance to mapper and I used this instance in ConstructUsing method to replace constructor with instance.

```
        ListItem instance = this.CreateListItemInstance();

        ListItem parsed = mapper.Map<ListItem>(model, opts =>
        opts.Items["instance"] = instance);  //passing instance to ResolutioContext

        this.SharePointListItemRepository.Insert(parsed);
        this.Save();
```

Inside map profile:

```
            CreateMap<Model, ListItem>()
            //Using 'ConstructUsing' method to use instance of Model 
            //(from resolutionContext) as constructor.
            .ConstructUsing((source, resolutionContext) => 
            (resolutionContext.Items["instance"] as ListItem))
            //Mappings...
            .AfterMap((source, destination) =>
            {
                destination["Title"] = source.Title;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#custom-constructor-methods):

> Because we only supplied the type of the custom resolver to AutoMapper, the mapping engine will use reflection to create an instance of the value resolver.
>
> If we don't want AutoMapper to use reflection to create the instance, we can supply it directly:
>
> ```
> Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
>     .ForMember(dest => dest.Total,
>         opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver())
>     );
> ```

In place of

```
opt.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver())
```

there may be:

```
opt.ResolveUsing(CreateListItemInstance())
```